# Image hover function (css) doesn't find image

Tags: html, css, image, mouseover

I want to have a button with an image and a link. Here is my style-code:

```
<style>
    twitter{

    display:block;
    background-image: url('CIMA/Social/Twitter.png');
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
}
</style>
```

and my body code:

```
<twitter href="#"> &nbsp; </twitter>
```

But it doesnt show any image. I tried a lot of different image-paths, but it just will not show...

Comment: Is css getting applied? Did you check in browser developer tools? If it is then it must be an issue of image path.

Comment: There is no such element as `<twitter>`

Comment: What's wrong with using your own elements? It can work: http://jsfiddle.net/64tF4/

Comment: well i'm new to html/css.
if twitter is not an element. what element do i have to use?

Comment: inspect your element with your browser, maybe the problem is not the element but the url on the css file, just right click the element and click on Inspect and you will have a lot of information there to debug

Answer (score 0):

oh. why not

```
<a href="#"><img src= "cima/social/twitter.png" /> </a>
<style>
a img {width:30%;height:30%;}
</style>
```

Comment: well this works, but I need this type of code from above, because i want to make a "hover" effect...

Comment: well, you should first create your element "twitter" http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp . But i don't understand why you can't apply hover effect for what i suggested!

Comment: well how do i implement the hover effect with your method? i only find tutorials for "my" method...

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is invalid as you are using custom (non-valid) elements. Try

**HTML**

```
<a class="twitter" href="#"> &nbsp; </a>
```

**CSS**

```
.twitter{

    display:block;
    background-image: url('CIMA/Social/Twitter.png');
    width: 30px; /* or whatever value */
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: actually this doesnt work, too. :( 
what could it be?

Comment: genius!! Thanks alot :)
But can i get this with: height/weight in "%" too?